# Sending float from arduino to python with serial

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to send a float from arduino, and read it with python using serial.

I'm generating numbers on the arduino with the following code:

This is the arduino code, it works

```
long randNumber;
float avgMe;
float theTemp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // initialize print
  Serial.println("Start session");
}

void loop() {
  avgMe = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randNumber = random(0, 11);
    delay(100);
    avgMe = avgMe + randNumber;
  }
  theTemp = avgMe / 10;
  Serial.print(theTemp);

}
```

It prints what i want to grab in python:

```
Start session
4.90
6.80
3.90
5.70
6.10
```

This is what i trid in python to grab it:

```
# %% Import
import serial
import time
import struct

# %% connect
try:
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=.1)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Connection to " + 'port' + " established succesfully!\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# %% loop for some time
t_end = time.time() + 10
while time.time() < t_end:
    data = ser.read(4)
    if data:
        # test = struct.unpack(">fff",data)
        print(data)

time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

Python prints:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00'
```

But firstly i can't convert that, also it doesn't seem like the information is there. I would love your input on this

Comment: Your Refresh rates are different. the Arduino is sending data at `9600` while python is collecting at `115200`. They need to be the same for data transfer to work correctly.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you! It worked. Please answer so i can upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem I had when I was first learning how to send data over a serial port from an arduino. The baud rates have to be the same or the outputs will turn out weird and wonderful.

If the arduino is using this baud rate

```
Serial.begin(9600); // initialize print
```

then python needs the same baud rate

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=.1)
```